# Gridview only supports horizontal gravity?

Tags: android, layout

I just want to confirm that android's GridView only supports horizontal gravity for its children? I see in the docs it says [setGravity(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setGravity%28int%29): "Describes how the child views are horizontally aligned. Defaults to Gravity.LEFT"

If that is correct then what is the best way to get my items to vertically align bottom? I think one option is to wrap each item in a parent view (such as FrameLayout) of a fixed height and give the contents gravity bottom. Is that the best choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer here is: **YES**, gridview only supports horizontal gravity.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the feeling you are confusing "gravity" with "orientation". Orientation can be either horizontal or vertical. While gravity takes values like top, down, left, right, etc..

The GridView comes in columns by nature starting from the left. Yet it can view data horizontally and vertically. Check this link http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

In your case, if I understood correctly, you want to align items vertically from the bottom. Best way is to use a LinearLayout, set its orientation to vertical, and set the gravity to bottom.